Is a select all checkbox that selects all sub-form checkboxes accessible?
I have a form with multiple fieldsets, and each fieldset has a set of checkboxes. My customer wants to add a select all button to select all checkboxes within each fieldset. I don't think this is an accessible approach, but I am curious if there is an accessible way to do this.
According to WCAG, the way to implement a mixed-state checkbox is this:
<fieldset class="checkbox-mixed">
  <legend>
    Sandwich Condiments
  </legend>
  <div role="checkbox"
       class="group_checkbox"
       aria-checked="mixed"
       aria-controls="cond1 cond2 cond3 cond4"
       tabindex="0">
    All condiments
  </div>
  <ul class="checkboxes">
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cond1">
        Lettuce
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
               id="cond2"
               checked="">
        Tomato
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cond3">
        Mustard
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cond4">
        Sprouts
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>

I tried wrapping all of the fieldsets within another fieldset with a legend that identifies all of these as grouped together, but the screen reader I use, voiceover on mac, does not read out the overall legend. Further researching has indicated that wrapping a fieldset within another fieldset is not a good general practice for accessibility purposes. I could use an aria-label for the checkbox to give context, but generally the best practice is to use the language semantics such that screen readers can get the correct context as using aria-label is more of a crutch.

If you have a layout that works fine in a screen reader, then why not simply hide the extra 'select all' checkbox from screen readers? Now both get a good experience.
